# Error installing ruby-1.9.3-p125 version in (Mac OSX Lion)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I am able to successfully install ruby versions.

- ruby-1.9.2-p330 [ x86_64 ]
- ruby-1.9.3-p484 [ x86_64 ]

But I am getting error when I try to install ruby-1.9.3-p125

Following is the error

```
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #removing src/ruby-1.9.3-p125..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p125.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Warning: found user selected compiler 'gcc-4.2', this will suppress RVM auto detection mechanisms.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/maygupta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p125, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p125 to /Users/maygupta/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125....
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #applying patch /Users/maygupta/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.9.3/p125/cflags.patch.
Patch cflags was already applied.
Patch cflags was already applied.
Patch cflags was already applied.
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #applying patch /Users/maygupta/.rvm/patches/ruby/GH-488.patch.
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #autoreconf.
Error running '__rvm_autoreconf',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/maygupta/.rvm/log/1415792353_ruby-1.9.3-p125/autoreconf.log
    \autoreconf "$@" || return $?
}
current path: /Users/maygupta/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125
GEM_HOME=/Users/maygupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p330
PATH=/Users/maygupta/.rvm/usr/bin:/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/Users/maygupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p330/bin:/Users/maygupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p330@global/bin:/Users/maygupta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p330/bin:/Users/maygupta/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:~/groupon-bin
GEM_PATH=/Users/maygupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p330:/Users/maygupta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p330@global
command(1): __rvm_autoreconf
++ autoreconf
aclocal: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
configure.in:427: warning: underquoted definition of RUBY_TRY_CFLAGS
configure.in:427:   run info Automake 'Extending aclocal'
configure.in:427:   or see http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Extending-aclocal
aclocal: error: aclocal: file '/usr/local/share/aclocal/mysql.m4' does not exist
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
++ return 1
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #configuring.............................................
Error running 'env CFLAGS=-O3 -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib ./configure --prefix=/Users/maygupta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml --without-tcl --without-tk --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/maygupta/.rvm/log/1415792353_ruby-1.9.3-p125/configure.log
checking for prefix of external symbols... _
checking pthread.h usability... yes
checking pthread.h presence... yes
checking for pthread.h... yes
checking for if make is GNU make... yes
checking for nroff... /usr/bin/nroff
.ext/include/x86_64-darwin12.5.0/ruby/config.h updated
ruby library version = 1.9.1
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --without-tcl, --without-tk
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --without-tcl, --without-tk
config.status: creating ruby-1.9.pc
./configure: line 18922: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./configure: line 18925: syntax error: unexpected end of file
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

#### Versions

- OS X - 10.8.5
- Xcode - 5.1.1

Output of `cc --version`

```
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Can someone suggest what's wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you installing it?

Comment: It looks like you have a ~/.rvmrc file which is supplying compilation settings, but you don't show anything in your question.

Comment: I am installing it through "rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p125"

Comment: Also yes I do have a ~/.rvmrc file and it only has the flag rvm_project_rvmrc_default=1